# how to make frequency divider?

Tags: digital-logic, frequency, flipflop

Can anybody show me how to make divider by 3 frequency using flip flop and logic gate ?

Does anyone here have any good suggestions ?

Comment: Why can't you look it up for yourself?

Comment: There must be thousands of examples of this on the net

Comment: @LeonHeller i've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a basic divide by 4 circuit.

[image]

when it gets to the 4th count (A = '1' AND B = '1') reset it and it starts again at zero

Comment: so, do you mean that i have to connect the reset to ground in order to make the count start again at zero ?

Comment: @Yogi - No reset needs a HIGH signal to operate it (If it has a bar over it (NOT reset) it means connect to LOW to operate it) - the output from the **AND** gate is connected to the reset input. When A AND B are high ('1') its output will be high.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a basic divider using two-bit counter. The algorithm:

1. Increment the counter on each clock edge
2. Let the counter count 0,1,2... When the counter equals 2: your divided clock goes high and the counter returns to 0.

This algorithm is basic and produces non-50% duty cycle clock.

If you have additional requirements, I suggest that you check [this forum](http://www.edaboard.com/thread48149.html) - there is no need to reinvent anything.